# Print nothing in Python

Tags: python

I have below code

```
choose = 4
print(choose if choose == 4 else None)

## this print 4
```

But,

```
choose = 5
print(choose if choose == 4 else None)
```

But this print `None` in the screen. Is there any way to print `NOTHING`?

Comment: Use `else ""` instead of `else None`.

Comment: Don't call `print` if you don't want to print something. Use an `if` statement.

Comment: how about not using `else` at all? Just define print inside `if choose == 4: print(choose)`

Comment: Just do `if choose == 4: print(choose)`. Why overcomplicate things? If you think  your single line will be faster, it won't

Comment: Why is `NOTHING` formatted as code? Surely you don't want `print(choose if choose == 4 else "NOTHING")`, right?

Comment: the methods of `None` are read-only, i.e. `__str__`, `__format__`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. If, by nothing, you mean a blank space, then you can use the following code:

```
choose = 5
print(choose if choose == 4 else "")
```

Or, if you want to print the text ‘NOTHING’, then you just have to modify the above code:

```
choose = 5
print(choose if choose == 4 else "NOTHING")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
choose = 5
print(choose if choose == 4 else '')
```

You could print NOTHING by printing an empty string.

Comment: It still prints a newline character (it's not really clear if this is what the OP wants or not).